# Count amount, do not count duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

So I have a table like this but with thousands of rows and what I want to do is for example count all the amount of times that "Monday" appears on this list (per category), but I only want to count Monday once per day (for example here MONDAY appears 3 times for category A on 01/02/2020 but I want it to only count it once for that day, and then also count it once for 02/02/2020 giving me a total of 2 times that Monday appears for Category A) how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, using two helper columns: in column "F" you concatenate the day, the category and the date, something like:

```
=D2&A2&C2
```

Then, in column "G", you use the following formula:

```
In G2, you just put 1.  
In G3, and deeper, you put: =IF(F2=F3;G2+1;1)
```

This "G" column will start at 1 and increase every time the same entry is found in column "F", but once this changes, it'll start at 1 again.

Then, you can use the values in the "G" column as a basis for a criteria (`CountIf()`, `SumIf()`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I would run a pivot table on the data:

[image: Pivot Table]